# Entity Framework large dataset (1800 rows), Order by Desc Not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

My ViewModel

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public List<Billing_Lab_Schedule> Items { get; set; }

}
```

Retrieving the data

```
            if (OrderBy == "6")
            {
                if (SortBy == "Asc")
                {
                    viewModel.Items = context.Billing_Lab_Schedule
                        .OrderBy(a => a.ModifyDate).Skip(Page * PageSize)
                        //.Where(a => a.ServiceCode.Contains(Code) && a.ServiceDesc.Contains(Description))
                        //.Take(PageSize)
                        .AsQueryable()
                        .ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    viewModel.Items = context.Billing_Lab_Schedule
                        .OrderByDescending(a => a.ModifyDate).Skip(Page * PageSize)
                        //.Where(a => a.ServiceCode.Contains(Code) && a.ServiceDesc.Contains(Description))
                        //.Take(PageSize)
                        .AsQueryable()
                        .ToList();
                }
```

The order by descending is leaving out recently changed values, however the order by has them at the very end of the list. I restarted my computer because I thought something was caching. I'm not sure why they are begin left out of the list when I order by desending.

Comment: It should work. Are you sure by putting a breakpoint into the else block that your code run inside that block ?

Comment: What if you put ToList() before OrderBy?

Comment: Yes calling .tolist() before the order by works.                         viewModel.Items = context.Billing_Lab_Schedule
                            .ToList()
                            .OrderByDescending(a => a.ModifyDate)
                            .AsQueryable()
                            .ToList();

Comment: Sorry It was the page skip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think skip is the one which is causing it since it normally skips the specified number of elements from top, try without it.

Answer (score 0):

try running toList before the sorting. Also inspect where you are calling savechanges.